# Convert rowname char(X1, X2, ... Xn) to num(1,2,...n)

Tags: r, dataframe

I've created a new data frame and the rownames got named like char(X1, X2, X3, ... Xn).

In order to merge the new data frame with an old one I need them to be num(1,2,3,...,n).

```
# Create DB with Topics
df_test <- data.frame(doc_topic_distr)
setDT(df_test, keep.rownames = "doc_id")
```

I've tried to  `df_test$doc_id <- as.integer(gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', df$doc_id))`them afterwards, but that's not working. :/

Any clues for this one?

/e:Here we go:

```
> df_test$doc_id <- gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', df$doc_id)
Error in df$doc_id : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> 
> dput(head(doc_topic_distr))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 0, 0.08, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.32, 
0, 0, 0.875, 0.407407407407407, 0, 0.16, 0, 0.166666666666667, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0.0740740740740741, 0, 0.12, 
0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 0, 0.04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.08, 0, 
0, 0, 0.0740740740740741, 0.25, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0.037037037037037, 
0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0.222222222222222, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.037037037037037, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.16, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim = c(6L, 
31L), .Dimnames = list(c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), NULL))
´´´
Many thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Not worksing meaning? `as.integer(gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', c("X1", "X2", "X3")))`

Comment: We need `dput(head(doc_topic_distr))`.

Comment: Instead of changing the names later, you can just assign `row.names(df_test) <- NULL` and then do the `setDT`

Comment: Hey folks, thanks for your replies ! I've edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(doc_topic_distr)
df <- cbind(doc_id = rownames(df), df)
df$doc_id <- as.numeric(as.character(df$doc_id))
```